# Getting a plenty of remarks including <afxwin.h>

Tags: mfc, remarks

Visual Studio 2017: I created a Windows project (Windows desktop wizard -> Windows App(Empty)).

Set MFC to use MFC in a shared DLL. Included `<afxwin.h>`.

And got a plenty of remarks in error list.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp2k4.png)

Code is here:

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class CMyWnd : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CMyWnd()
    {
        Create(nullptr, _T("Just an stupid app ,isn`t it?"));
    }
};

class CMyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance() override;
};

BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    m_pMainWnd = new CMyWnd;
    m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
    return TRUE;
}
CMyApp MainApp;
```

However, the program works.
What is going on? How can I repair it or just turn off errors in this header?
(I am a bit new here so please correct me if I am not right anywhere)
Thanks!

Comment: You are missing header files. Go to File->New, create a new MFC project "dialog based application", then change the code to what you have now.

Comment: but why i cant just make it from the "plain windows project"? I can compile it.It works, even more the same project in VS 2015 I dont get such a bad mistakes.I just want to understand what a difference (cause I am reading now  Hortons book Beggining Visual c++ 2013).Thanks for decision it works))

Comment: These are intellisense errors of the MFC source, which can be ignored. You can remove these from the error output via the drop-down field on the top right of the error window (press the small arrow button on the right to see it).

Comment: Thanks! That what I wanted!